# Will SSL handshake work when a JKS keystore have an expired self-signed certificate and a valid CA signed certificate?

Tags: java, ssl, ssl-certificate, jks

The self-signed certificate in a JKS keystore.jks has validity of only around 4 months, whereas the CA signed certificate will have validity of around 2 years, so when the self-signed certificate expires, will it not create any problem in SSL handshake?

Comment: You can make self-signed jks keystores have whatever lifetime you like.  I habitually use 365 days.   As to whether anyone cares whether it expires, it depends on whether the client code cares/does not care whether it expires.  (You'll have seen browsers saying 'expired cert' that let you connect anyway. This means they internally control whether they care about expiration, or not).

Comment: Why don't you just try it? Generating an expired self-signed certificate shouldn't be too difficult. Or just change your clock.

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate is added to the **truststore** that the socket uses (creating an array of `TrustManager`s and passing that to an `SSLContext`), then the `SSLSocket` seems to treat it as valid. Testing this using a dummy certificate that expires 1 second after creation, this seems to be correct; the client connects without exceptions or issues and can send messages.

Therefore, if the client in question explicitly trusts the certificate, the client should be able to connect.

However, if another implementation is being used that rejects expired certificates, the client will most likely throw an exception.